# Install Certificate via Script from SST, Automatically Select Certificate Store

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am running a program which detects changes in Windows, one of the changes it looks for are added certificates due to a program, the issue is that I keep seeing false positives due to Windows Auth Root Updater. My resolution to this was to get a list of certificates from Windows using

```
Certutil -generateSSTFromWU <filename>
```

and install that using a script. However, once I try and install the certificates from that file via command line, all options I have seen require me to specify a store. In the certificate install wizard there is an option for *Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate* as seen below

[image: Certificate Install Wizard]

Is there a way to accomplish this from a script?

Thank you for your advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the rootsupd.exe is actually from Microsoft. From what I can remember though it just uses MS best guess method of where to actually store the certs. I'd recommend using PowerShell's `Import-Certificate` as you can actually specify which store you want it in.

As for the time-stamping certificate CAs you typically see them in countersignatures of the certificate that signed the package. For a valid package you would need to be able to verify both signed and counter-signed CAs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when importing root certificates, all of them should go to the local computer root store anyhow...

```
mkdir ~\rootcerts
cd ~\rootcerts

certutil.exe -generateSSTFromWU .\rootcerts.sst
$sstFile = (Get-ChildItem -Path .\rootcerts.sst)
$sstFile | Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

Now, if you'd like to do some filtering on the way, you'd need to handle the certificates one by one and throwing in some .Net...

The example below would only import available updated Comodo certificates...

```
mkdir ~\rootcerts
cd ~\rootcerts
certutil -syncWithWU .\

[array]$certs = $null

$crtfiles = get-item *.crt

foreach ($file in $crtfiles) {
   $certObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($file)
   $certs += $certObj
}

$CertStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store `
   -ArgumentList  "\\$($ENV:COMPUTERNAME)\My", "LocalMachine"
$CertStore.Open('ReadWrite') 

$certs | Where Issuer -like 'CN=Comodo Cert*' | foreach {$CertStore.Add($_)}

$CertStore.Close()
```

(rootsupd.exe as sugested in other answers isn't easily available from the correct source, MS.)

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find a solution which somewhat works, using the rootsupd.exe file, I was able to get rid of a few certificate entries that were appearing. I included a link to where I found the executable.

https://support.kaspersky.com/13727

In order to run this file, I opened PowerShell as administrator, navigated to the file directory, and executed the command

```
.\rootsupd.exe
```

Using a script I wrote that dumps the certificates to a text file, I was then able to diff before and after to determine that certificates were being added.

As another note, by unpacking the rootsupd.exe package using the command

```
rootsupd.exe /c /t:<filepath>
```

You can then find a file called updroots.exe in the filepath which when used with an sst file as such,

```
updroots.exe <sst file>
```

You can install an sst file.

However, I am still seeing a lot of the timestamping certificates and codesigning certificates, such as:

Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010
Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010
Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA
GlobalSign Timestamping CA - G2
Microsoft Code Signing PCA

If anyone has any suggestions in order to prevent these from being added or preemptively add them, that would be incredibly helpful. I have attempted to disable Windows Auth Root Update, which would not be a convenient solution, since if a program might need certificates and I would like to see that addition. Despite disabling that service, I still see these timestamping and codestamping certs. If anyone has any advice that would be great.

EDIT: I will open a new question, since the issue has changed to a different subject.

New Question At:
    [Time-Stamp Certificates are Installed, What is Installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562645/time-stamp-certificates-are-installed-what-is-installing-them)

Comment: Please add a disclaimer that rootsupd.exe isn't a MS download link. The link do say "Kaspersky", but it should be provided from MS.