# Time-Stamp Certificates are Installed, What is Installing them?

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I am currently working on a scripted program which tracks changes in the operating system by taking snapshots of certain things. One of these are the certificates. The goal being to see what changes an installed program makes to the system. The current issue is that I keep seeing certificates being added that the program did not add, Windows did. My goal was to prevent Windows from downloading certificates during the test. By installing a brand new Trust Root Authority certificates store using the commands:

```
CertUtil -GenerateSSTFromWU <filename>
```

Followed by:

```
updroots.exe <filename>
```

The issue is that after installing this new store, while I do see fewer certificates being added, I continue to see a number of time-stamp certificates being added to the CurrentUser/CA store. I was hoping someone knew where these certificates we coming from and how I could perhaps pre-install them so they do not appear during the test. Thank you for your advice.

Edit:
Examples of certificates include,

Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA 2010
Microsoft Code Signing PCA 2010
Microsoft Time-Stamp PCA
GlobalSign Timestamping CA - G2
Microsoft Code Signing PCA

Edit 2.0:
Was looking around, I had mentioned that it installed the certificates in the Current User/CA store, which appears to correspond to the Intermediate Certificate Authorities store in certmgr. I believe that AuthRootAutoUpdate applies to the Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store. The question I am looking into now, is there a separate service responsible for updating Intermediate Certificate Authorities?

Comment: Can you provide example names of the certs and where they are appearing? Windows does have a number of default trusted certificates that are installed and are updated via updates and communication with Microsoft certificate server etc. For ex. Certificate revokation lists. The key thing is you need to have some root certificates for your computer to work (e.g. to access www), and these are going to change (e.g. certs expire and are renewed). Essentially, fully update your computer, then take your snapshot.

Comment: Examples of the certificates were added to the question, the software is running in a Virtual Machine which is fully updated

Comment: Trusted root certificates that are required by Windows Server: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/293781/trusted-root-certificates-that-are-required-by-windows-server-2008-r2

Comment: Probably should have included, I am on Windows 10, and I did not see any of the certificates I am seeing on the list you linked to.

Comment: Try manually updating the cert list `Certutil -syncWithWU \\Server1\CTL` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)

Comment: I have looked through the certificates downloaded by the command and none of them match the certificates I am seeing. I believe it must be a separate service that is downloading the timestamp and codesigning certificates. Especially considering that Certutil Windows Update features depend on AuthRoot Auto Update, which is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has started an project where root certificates are added inside the code, probably crypt32.dll. If no internet connection is possible it takes a fews seconds and then they will be copied from the dll. For more information see link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/participants-list.

If you are running `Get-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath <some exe or dll file>` you could force this.

Regards, Thomas S.

Answer (score 0):

Windows try to get certificates from ctldl.windowsupdate.com. Firstly it try to get following files:

```
http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/disallowedcertstl.cab
http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab
```

And then it can take root certificates if it needs them to check identity of certificates from folder:

```
http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, I was wondering if you had any more information. How did you find those links? Do you know how to go about ensuring it doesn't download more certificates?

Comment: I have problem with certificates identity at work. We use proxy at work. And some sites didn't work because of untrusted certificates. I tried to  figure out why they didn't works. I used wireshrark (packet sniffer) and saw http get request to links that i mentioned in previous post. I allow them on proxy and solve problem with certificates. If you don't want get root certificates you must forbid access to folder: http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/

Comment: Ok, I think that might be part of the AuthRootUpdater, it might also be related to the content found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)). Not sure if it explains why these timestamp and codesigning certificates are still appearing.

Comment: Maybe they appear because signed programs execute on computer. And this programs are signed with that codesign certificates and windows download them to check that programs signed with valid certs. See by which certificates programs were signed. Maybe you see this codesign certificates in trust chain

Comment: The program I am using as a test was signed using a globalsign certificate, that does not appear to be the case. Thanks for the suggestion.